# Trouble with HTML/CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I've got a main page with a menu that works fine on full screen. But when it's on smaller screens, the display is messed up.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dgac3j5/5/) of the current situation. If you change the canvas size you can see how the elements behave.

For example, I've tried to insert percentual values but it doesn't work: I've tried to edit the `#top-section` like this:

```
#top-section {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 95.75%; height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: White;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But it is not behaving as I wanted. I started with the top section but I want the `.breadcrumbs` and the `.main-window` to display nicely if the screen is smaller but I'm having lots of trouble.

Any help?

Comment: try to narrow this down to where you think the issue is coming from, having to go through the entire code is not helping a lot...

Comment: you could use `CSS3 @media queries` - http://jsfiddle.net/7dgac3j5/2/

Comment: one solution could be to set a `min-width` for the main content box. that would mean that things wouldn't get crushed, but on small screen there would be a horizontal scroll. i'm not posting as an answer because this may not be an acceptable tradeoff for you.

Comment: @webeno, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/7dgac3j5/5/) an updated fiddle with less CSS. Also updated in the question

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow, the menu buttons being crushed is a part of the problem and your suggestion could actually fix that, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a more specific definition of how you want the page to display on a small screen? Your question states 'display nicely' but this is very subjective.

Comment: chiapa, I actually recommend the solution by @MaryMelody over mine -- although I suppose a `min-width` would be super easy to implement.

Comment: @Candlejack, you are right: by "display nicely" I meant that the breadcrumbs section doesn't disappear, the top section shrinks as the screen size shrinks (like a relative height value) and the position of the `.main-window` class isn't fixed but moves with the screen size adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the `.breadcrumbs` section disappearing and the `.main-window` container adjusting with the screen size. To fix this you need to stop using `position: absolute;` on these `div`s (which takes elements out of the document flow) and instead allow the `div`s to stack in the normal document flow.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6g2hdzqk/1/

**EDIT**

The issue with the `OCW` button is due to the buttons being `floated` and the `outer-height` of the button changing when hovered (due to the change in `border-width`) causing the `BRG` button to nudge up against the `TLM` button.

Made a few further changes (changed the buttons to be `inline-block` instead of `floated` to the `left`) and incorporated the font suggestion by @Danield (+1d) which seems to fix most display problems.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6g2hdzqk/2/

Comment: There's a behaviour issue when you hover over the `OCW` button, did you sse it?

Comment: Sorry, did you alter any markup? Because I'm using your CSS but it isn't looking very nice! I was wondering if you altered the HTML

Comment: Two changes to the markup, `<section class="content-wrapper clear-fix">` was removed as it was no longer needed and the `clear-fix` class was added to `<div class="main-window">`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer guided me to the result I needed. `+1`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting a fixed value of 70px for your font-size, consider using the new css viewport units.

Something like `font-size: 7vw;` (= 7% of the viewport width)

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7dgac3j5/7/)** (Resize the window to see this in action)

```
.menu-text {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7vw; /* <-- here */
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    line-height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `+1` I didn't know that. That fixes the font issue. Still, the other problems remain

Answer (score 0):

You have to define width with non-percent value (95%), for example `800px` at `.main-window` class.

Comment: That will fixed width that won't display correctly on smaller screens

Comment: Yes but if is smaller screen then the big letters will be hidden.If you have not problem with that you can play with overflow.